# How to Send and Receive XML request to another ASP classic page?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I want to send an XML to another Asp Classic page on the same domain. i am using following code for sending XMl

```
url = "http://localhost/api/xmlget.asp"
information = "<Send><UserName>Colt</UserName><PassWord>Taylor</PassWord><Data>100</Data></Send>"
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml" 
xmlhttp.send information
```

And i have setup xmlget.asp with following code to receive XML:

```
 Dim xmlDoc
 Dim userName
 set xmlDoc=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 xmlDoc.async="false"
 xmlDoc.load(Request)
```

I run the code but do not see any reflection, how would i know? And if it is successful I want to know the xml and i dont know exact property to load from xmlDoc!

Answer (score 1):

First: You are not sending XML.
The variable information only have a simple text. Try

```
information = "<a>ColtTaylor100</a>"
```

Second: Why are you using Microsoft.XMLDOM instead of MSXML2.DOMDocument?
I have use it with MSXML2 and worked fine.

```
Dim xmlDoc
set xmlDoc=Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
if not xmlDoc.load(Request) then
   Response.Write xmlDoc.parseerror.reason
   Response.End
end if
```